The import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals cannot be resolved
when I build maven project as a eclipse-plugin then getting issue but with jar packaging its working fine.
issue I get when packaging is eclipse-plugin
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals; [ERROR] [ERROR] The import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals cannot be resolved
I tried adding --add-module java.smartcardio while running maven build

In eclipse also I got the compile time error but after adding madule java.smartcardio then its gone but not able to maven build as eclipse-plugin packaging.
I am using openjdk-17
Thanks

An Eclipse plug-in can only access things in its own Bundle-Classpath or exported by other plug-ins by using Require-Bundle or Import-Package

Why do you get the error only when building? Aren't problems already displayed when you open the Eclipse plugin project in the Eclipse IDE?

Its strange, not sure why I am getting this compilation error while building eclipse-plugin project. even it is working with jar packaging.
I am also able to run eclipse plugin and I can see my plugin is working fine.

In eclipse IDE,  Its included in jre only but still I have to add module dependency from build path then only it is compiling classes from javax.smartcardio module

That's not how you set up a plug-in classpath in Eclipse. You must use the Dependencies tab in the MANIFEST.MF editor. You can't treat a plug-in like a normal Java project. Also plug-ins don't generally use a module-info.java

Is your project a plugin project,  in the Package Explorer or Project Explorer with a Plug-in Dependencies node (which by the way can be expanded to check what dependencies there are) shown below the project folder? If yes, please show your MANIFEST.MF file? You do not have a module-info.java file, right?

here is manifest.mf content -
//Removed some basic deatails like bundle-version,bundle-name etc.,
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.smartcardplugin
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Import-Package: javax.smartcardio,
org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
org.slf4j,
javax.smartcardio
Export-Package: com.example.smartcardplugin
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
org.eclipse.osgi

@howlger I am not using module-info.java.

Please edit your question and insert the content of your MANIFEST.MF file, formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks). Import-Package: contains the Java package javax.smartcardio twice. Please show your pom.xml file and your target definition file. You still didn't tell whether it's a plugin project or not and how you add the JAR containing javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals. Maybe you added it to the project's Build Path which would be wrong. You need to add it as plugin/bundle to your target platform.

Yes, it is plugin project.
